# threejs mesh missing triangle

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, webgl, polygons

threejs is having some serious issues with some polygons

I'm on their site, viewing their examples.

On my computer, It starts out fine, like the first image below, but within a few seconds, becomes the mess in the second part of that image.

you can see that it works in your browser [here](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_skinning_morph.html)

I've tried clearing my history, cache, cookies, anything I can think of. I've even switched Firefox from Chrome. nothing seems to work.

any ideas? is this a webgl issue?

[image: before and after some glitch happens in ThreeJS,]

Comment: Well its been running for 5 minutes in my latest chrome with no visible issues. It probably has to do with your machine and/or browser.

Comment: install latest gpu drivers, just in case.

Comment: Tried updating my GPU. no dice. I have an amd 3400, and I even updated to the beta. no change. Again, I tried in both firefox and chrome

Comment: I just uninstalled AMD Catalyst drivers, and now it's working normally.

Comment: Make an answer to this question yourself and accept it so the topic could be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an AMD Catalyst driver issue. I uninstalled it and the issue was resolved. It's now using the default drivers. I'll update if I ever install new drivers, but for now I'm leaving it as is.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer so that your question topic is closed.

Comment: Indeed, When I first posted it, it was still before the time that I could accept my own :)